# Differential Operators over the space of Analytic Functions

Tags: normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, differential-operators

Let $\mathcal{A}(-a,a)$ be the vector space of functions that are analytic on the interval $(-a,a)$

Is there a common topology to place on this space, if yes what is the topology and is it induced by a norm?

What can be said about differential operators over this space? Are they bounded/unbounded? Would there be a natural topology to place on the space of differential operators over $\mathcal{A}(-a,a)$?